# Spark Structured Streaming complete mode is not working as expected

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have created a Structured Streaming job that looks as given below. In the first pass I added only one file in the INPUT_DIRECTORY & it worked fine. My understanding is that, if a new EXACT SAME file is added to the same directory, the counts would double because I am using the 'complete' mode. But that's not happening. Is my understanding of "complete" mode wrong? Here's the code:

```
    Dataset<StoreSales> storeSalesStream = spark
            .readStream()
            .schema(storeSalesSchema)
            .csv(INPUT_DIRECTORY)
            .as(Encoders.bean(StoreSales.class));


    //When data arrives from the stream, these steps will get executed

    //4 - Create a temporary table so we can use SQL queries
    storeSalesStream.createOrReplaceTempView("storeSales");

    String sql = "SELECT AVG(ss_quantity) as average_quantity, count(*) as cnt, ss_store_sk FROM storeSales GROUP BY ss_store_sk order by ss_store_sk";
    Dataset<Row> ageAverage = spark.sql(sql);

    //5 - Write the the output of the query to the console
    StreamingQuery query = ageAverage.writeStream()
            .outputMode("complete")
            .format("console")
            .start();

    query.awaitTermination();
```

Output with one file:

```
+------------------+------+-----------+
|  average_quantity|   cnt|ss_store_sk|
+------------------+------+-----------+
| 50.60551037038176|130035|       null|
|50.550020846689414|456896|          1|
|  50.5936442439659|458159|          2|
| 50.43842163027273|458272|          4|
| 50.55502265092984|458194|          7|
| 50.47613176523048|459357|          8|
| 50.47919908681093|459492|         10|
+------------------+------+-----------+
```

Output after copying a new (exact same) file:

```
+------------------+------+-----------+
|  average_quantity|   cnt|ss_store_sk|
+------------------+------+-----------+
| 50.63186245101668|156491|       null|
| 50.54070128518595|549167|          1|
|50.600774270842244|550477|          2|
| 50.46126613833389|550604|          4|
| 50.57143520798298|551066|          7|
| 50.46779475780309|552865|          8|
| 50.46881408984539|552466|         10|
+------------------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Does this work with a non-streaming batch query (Spark SQL)? Can you show the content of the file(s) and how you copy the new file? How many files do you have in your input directory?

Comment: Yes, it works fine under non-streaming environment. I've used 'stores_sales' table from 'tpcds' database (https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/dataset/TPCDS) for testing. It has 2,888,404 rows. I downloaded as a CSV. I start with a single CSV file which prints counts correctly as 'Batch 0'. Later I use 'cp tpcds_store_sales.csv tpcds_store_sales1.csv' command to make another copy of the same file in the same directory. My understanding is that the Structured Streaming will detect this new file & since I am using 'complete' mode, it will double the counts in 'Batch 1' but that's not happening!

Comment: Do I need to specify something like 'buffer size' or 'window size' or something like that?